# Swift - JSQMessagesViewController Showing incoming avatar email or username

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm developing a chat app,And  I have this[image]

The problem now is how can i show the username on top of the message bubbles like this on the demo? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/develop/Screenshots/screenshot2.png

I'm looking for `override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, senderDisplayNameDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource!` But I think it's not possible. What do you think the solution here? Thanks!

Comment: due to lack of flexibility If you need a full-flag messaging application I wouldn't recommend the JSQ, we ended up writing our own viewController which is pretty tricky too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For viewing userName top of the incoming message JSQ is having below methods.

```
//MARK: To View  usernames above bubbles

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item];

    // Sent by me, skip
    if message.sender() == sender {
        return nil;
    }

    // Same as previous sender, skip
    if indexPath.item > 0 {
        let previousMessage = messages[indexPath.item - 1];
        if previousMessage.sender() == message.sender() {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return NSAttributedString(string:message.sender())
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    // Sent by me, skip
    if message.sender() == sender {
        return CGFloat(0.0);
    }

    // Same as previous sender, skip
    if indexPath.item > 0 {
        let previousMessage = messages[indexPath.item - 1];
        if previousMessage.sender() == message.sender() {
            return CGFloat(0.0);
        }
    }

    return kJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellLabelHeightDefault
}
```

The above code is worked for me, I hope it will work for you also. For more info you can see Demo

https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView?, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout?, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    // Override point:
    //
    // Here we check for what our setting is for displaying the senderDisplayName 
    // if we dont want to display it we just return a height of 0.
    // Then we check to see if (The current user) 
    // sent the message if so we return 0, because we know our own name,
    // other wise we return the defualt height.
    //

    return kJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellLabelHeightDefault
}
```

That is what throws most people Let me know if that helps